# Call function by classname for multiple rows

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have function to update multiple table rows on button click. It should add a `selected` class into rows.

```
<button class=\"btn btn-flat\" onclick=\"if(confirm('Deseja realmente excluir o registro?')) window.location.href='".base_url("adm/pedidos/excluir/".$registro->id)."';\">
    <span class=\"awe-remove\"></span>
</button>";
<table class="datatable table table-bordered" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="t-center">Pedido</th>
            <th class="t-center">Data</th>
            <th>Cliente</th>
            <th class="t-center">Frete</th>
            <th class="t-center">Valor Total</th>
            <th class="t-center">Status</th>
            <th class="t-center">Pagamento</th>
            <th class="t-center">A&ccedil;&atilde;o</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach($registros as $registro)
            {
                echo "<tr class=\"".situacaoClasse($registro->situacao)."\">";
                echo '<td class="t-center">'.$registro->id.'</td>';
                echo "<td><span style='display:none;'>".$registro->data."</span>".converteDataHora($registro->data)."</td>";
                echo '<td class="pedidonome">'.strtolower($registro->nome ? $registro->nome : $registro->razao_social).' ('.$registro->uf.')</td>';
                echo '<td class="t-center">R$ '.ConverteReal($registro->frete).' ('.getTipoFrete($registro->tipo_frete).') <br> '.($registro->frete_prazo ? '<small>'.$registro->frete_prazo.'  dia(s) - '.ConverteData($registro->frete_prazo_data).'</small>' : '').'</td>';
                echo '<td class="t-center">R$ '.ConverteReal($registro->valor_pedido).'</td>';
                echo '<td class="t-center">'.$registro->situacao.'</td>';
                echo '<td class="t-center">'.getPagamento($registro->pagamento).'</td>';
                echo "<td class=\"toolbar\">
                <div class=\"btn-group\">
                <a class=\"btn btn-flat\" href=\"".base_url("adm/pedidos/alterar/".$registro->id)."\">
                <span class=\"awe-wrench\"></span>
                </a>
                ";

                if ($this->session->userdata('usuario_tipo') == 'adm')
                {
                    echo "
                    <button class=\"btn btn-flat\" onclick=\"if(confirm('Deseja realmente excluir o registro?')) window.location.href='".base_url("adm/pedidos/excluir/".$registro->id)."';\">
                    <span class=\"awe-remove\"></span>
                    </button>";
                }

                echo "
                </div>
                </td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But when I click the button, nothing is updated.

Comment: Interesting question for me! update without form and inputs ?

Comment: I dont know how do it using form, because my function is called byt $id from td selected

Comment: Sorry! I dont understand codeigniter,  see this tutorial https://webdamn.com/datatables-add-edit-delete-with-ajax-php-mysql/ might help

Comment: Probably if you post your rest of the code (the other two urls being called), we can find why it is not updating.